# Active Characters inside of a Matrix Environment

Tags: environments

In a document I am working on I need to typeset a large number of matrices of the form

```
\def\x{\mathrm{x}}
\def\X{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{pmatrix}
 & \x & \X & \x & \x\\
 &    & \X & \x & \x\\
 &    & \X & \x & \x\\
 &    & \X &    & \x\\
 &    &    &    &   \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

where each entry is either blank, an \x, or an \X.  I am wondering how best to go about defining an environment such that I could write

```
\begin{mymatrix}
 xXxx\\-Xxx\\-X-x\\-X--\\
\end{mymatrix}
```

using active characters I can easily change how `x`, `X`, and `-` expand inside of the environment.  However, the tricky bit is managing what they should expand to—specifically, how to manage the `&`.  As, we only want to expand a `&` if the next token is not a `\\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl
\seq_new:N \l_freddie_xxmatrix_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\Xxmatrix}{m}
 {
  % clear the variable that becomes the body of the matrix
  \tl_clear:N \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl
  % split at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_freddie_xxmatrix_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % insert & between each item
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_freddie_xxmatrix_seq
   {
    % split at each item
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { ##1 }
    % reconstitute the row with &
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { & }
     }
    % add the row to the body
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl { \\ }
   }
  % replace - with nothing, x with \mathrm{x}, X with \mathbf{x}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl { - } { }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl { x } { \mathrm{x} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl { X } { \mathbf{x} }
  % print the matrix
  \freddie_printmatrix:V \l_freddie_xxmatrix_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \freddie_printmatrix:n
 {
  \begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \freddie_printmatrix:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
\Xxmatrix{
 xXxx \\
 -Xxx \\
 ---- \\
 -X-x
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more classical version, with `-xX` made into math active characters. Remember the trailing `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Xxmatrix}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \makemathactive{x}{\freddiex}%
  \makemathactive{X}{\freddieX}%
  \makemathactive{-}{\freddienothing}%
  \begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}%
  \endgroup
}
\mathchardef\standardx=\mathcode`x
\newcommand{\makemathactive}[2]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \mathcode`#1="8000
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\freddiecheck}{\kernel@ifnextchar\\{}{&}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\freddiex}{\mathrm{\standardx}\freddiecheck}
\newcommand{\freddieX}{\mathbf{\standardx}\freddiecheck}
\newcommand{\freddienothing}{\freddiecheck}

\begin{document}
\[
\Xxmatrix{
 xXxx \\
 -Xxx \\
 ---- \\
 -X-x \\
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat, I haven't seen that syntax before.  Out of interest, do you think Luatex would have any advantage here in terms of coding the command?

Comment: @FreddieWitherden Possibly. The syntax is `expl3`, the programming layer of the future LaTeX3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still thinking how to resolve the extra column... I also used `Q` and `q` instead of `X` and `x`, since an active `x` would interfere with `pmatrix` invocation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\x{\mathrm{x}}
\def\X{\mathbf{x}}
\begin{document}
\[
\catcode`-=\active
\catcode`Q=\active
\catcode`q=\active
\def-{&}
\def Q{\X&}
\def q{\x&}
\begin{pmatrix}
qQqq\\-Qqq\\-Q-q\\-Q--\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following approach wallpapers over the extra column, using a negative kern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\x{\mathrm{x}}
\def\X{\mathbf{x}}
\def\backup{\kern-9pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\catcode`-=\active
\catcode`Q=\active
\catcode`q=\active
\def-{&}
\def Q{\X&}
\def q{\x&}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
qQqq\\-Qqq\\-Q-q\\-Q--\\
\end{matrix}
\backup\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]